# cannot find symbol class Random

Tags: java, random

When I run this code it technically shouldn't have any problem but I keep getting the error "cannot find symbol Random"
Is there anything I need to input in the beginning of the code!?

```
public class RandomNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        System.out.println("First number: " + r.nextInt(100));
        System.out.println("Second number: " + r.nextInt(100));
        System.out.println("Third number: " + r.nextInt(100));
        System.out.println("Fourth number: " + r.nextInt(100));
        System.out.println("Fifth number: " + r.nextInt(100));
    }
}
```

Comment: import class `import java.util.Random;`

Comment: import java.util.Random;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to import the [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class

```
import java.util.Random; // here

public class RandomNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        System.out.println("First number: " + r.nextInt(100));
        System.out.println("Second number: " + r.nextInt(100));
        System.out.println("Third number: " + r.nextInt(100));
        System.out.println("Fourth number: " + r.nextInt(100));
        System.out.println("Fifth number: " + r.nextInt(100));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you import Random? If you didn't just put

```
import java.util.Random
```

At the top

Answer (score 1):

Try import `java.util.Random` at the beginning.